# Dagger 2 is overlooking provides method

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

In my Android app I'm trying to get a DatabaseHelper object injected into ArticleView but Dagger complains with the following error message:

```
Error:(11, 7) error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
dk.jener.paperflip.ArticleActivity.database
[injected field of type: dk.jener.paperflip.model.retriever.DatabaseHelper database]
dk.jener.paperflip.model.retriever.DatabaseHelper.<init>(android.content.Context context)
[parameter: android.content.Context context]
```

How do I fix it?

My code is as follows:

```
@Singleton
@Module
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    @Inject
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "foobar", null, 1);
    }
    ...
}

@Module
public class ApplicationContextModule {
    private final Context context;

    public ApplicationContextModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = { DatabaseHelper.class })
public interface RetrieverComponent {
    void inject(ArticleActivity activity);
}

public class ArticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    DatabaseHelper database;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        RetrieverComponent component = DaggerRetrieverComponent.builder()
                .applicationContextModule(new ApplicationContextModule(getApplicationContext()))
                .build();
        component.inject(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

As far as I can figure Context is already provided by ApplicationContextModule#provideApplicationContext .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the provided code seems that you missed to include the `ApplicationContextModule` module in your component. It should be like:

```
@Component(modules = { ApplicationContextModule.class })
```

Also `DatabaseHelper` does not need to have `@Module` annotation (it is not a module but just a normal class).

Comment: Now that's fixed I get "databaseHelper must be set".

Comment: Probably it will be best to post another question with your current code (don't edit current answer)